# Lambda - DynamoDB Pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stream, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I am creating a simple matchmaking system using Lambda and DynamoDB.

For simplicity, imagine a game where you can bet 1$, 2$, and 5$. And people get matched based on the matching stake they bet.

I have a lambda function called 'findGame', it does:

1. Reads from DynamoDB and checks that there is not the same stake (if there is, then we match these 2 people (using WebSockets))
2. If no matching stake, we insert in the table the stake and the player's info

Now here is the problem: This works fine, until you consider that lambda can run in parallel. When testing, I figured that if 2 people clicked on 'findGame' at approximately the same time, both reads from the db will return nothing, and I will have both records in the db, without actually matchmaking them.

My temporary solution is to use DynamoDB Stream, which transforms my architecture into the following:

- Lambda function 'findGame': Inserts the record in the DB
- DynamoDB Stream -> Lambda function 'matchmake' -> On 'INSERT', I read from DB if there is a matching stake to matchmake them, and since streams are successive, this kind of fixes my problem. However, I have this feeling that having this architecture is wrong, as streams are mainly used for logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [conditional put](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites).

In case you have multiple concurrent inserts one will succeed and the rest will fail, then you can handle the error.

Something like

```js
client.putItem({
   TableName: "BettingGame",
   Item: {
     "PK": "user#john#bet#2",
     ...extra properties ...
   },
   ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(PK)'
})
```

Another option would be to use a transaction, but tey use 2x more capacity units.

Comment: This worked thanks! Although, I had to redesign my 'Lobby' table to only have the stake as a primary key.